# SQL как найти все группы в которых есть одно из значений?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется таблица `Orders` и таблица `OrderItem`, в которой перечислены товары на каждый отдельный заказ. Мне нужно найти только те заказы, в которые включен товар `103 (p_id = 103)`. То-есть, например, если человек покупал товары `105, 106, 110, 103`, этот заказ тоже считается, потому что он содержит товар 103. Возвращен будет avg всех этих заказов.

Comment: Тут не решают домашние задания за кого то, а помогают разобраться если что то не получается. что вы уже пробовали. для начала получите только ID требуемого заказа из OrderItem, такой запрос у вас получается ?

Comment: Гм... а что такое "avg заказов"?

Comment: @Akina, среднее значение

Comment: А структуру таблиц можно?

Comment: Что avg - это среднее, я знаю. А среднее, извините, чего именно? номера договора? количества итемов? суммы? даты оплаты?

Comment: @Akina, могу предположить, что цены товаров

Answer (score 3):

ну так сделайте выборку по заказам, сделайте правый джоин к ним позиций с условием что есть 103. Или, ещё проще, выберете уникальные ордер айди из позиций которые 103 и по этим айди возьмите все заказы.

Answer (score 0):

Запросом

```
select distinct IdOrder from OrderItem where IdItem = 103
```

Получаем список заказов в которых присутствует товар с `IdItem` равным 103.
Далее идем по таблице `OrderItem` и смотрим только те заказы, которые вернул нам предыдущий запрос. Каждый заказ объединяем в группу и соединяем с таблицей товаров `Items`, для получения цены. В итоге возвращаем `IdOrder`, т.е. наш ключ группировки и среднее арифметическое цен товаров вошедших в эту группу.

Конечный запрос имеет следующий вид:

```
select IdOrder, AVG(Item.Price) from OrderItem as t1
inner join Items on Items.Id = t1.IdItem
where t1.IdOrder in (select distinct IdOrder from OrderItem where IdItem = 1)
group by t1.IdOrder
```